# How to get authenticated Json object in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json

I want to get an object by using get request in angularJs. Server asks for authentication details: how to pass authentication details?

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://192.168.1.133:8080/xyz-api/api/customer/token/xyzname',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/JSON'
  }
}).success(function (data) {
  $scope.customerDetails = data;
  $scope.CUSTOMER_ID = $scope.customerDetails.id;
  $scope.companyName = $scope.customerDetails.name;
}).error(function () {
  alert('error');
});
```

Comment: generally you would pass authentication information in the header, but sending username and password in the header isn't really recommended;  this is more a question about the API you are using than angular, and a bit too broad to be answered without a lot more information....

Comment: Yeah i want to call an API and get the object details how to call an API using  angularjs

Comment: that doesn't clarify things any... You are already showing an example of calling an API, unless you are suggesting that you want to call a different API for an authentication object....   Either way, the details of how to do this will vary depending on your API, so without knowing what back end you are using and what it's authentication process is, this question isn't answerable.